# Firebase Unity Android: No google-services.json files found in your project

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I am trying to add Firebase to my Unity project but somehow it keeps giving me an annoying error.

I've tried to use `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.exe` myself but that didn't fix the problem. 
I also tried to edit the `generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py` python script to change the default location(which is set to a "normal" android app paths) but that didn't work either.

I followed the steps exactly from the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) and pasted the google-services.json fie in the root of the `assets` folder but it still gives me the following error:

```
No google-services.json files found in your project so it is not possible to 

generate Firebase Android resources file google-services.xml.
Building without Firebase Android resources (google-services.xml) will result in an app that will fail to initialize.

To resolve this problem, follow the setup instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#setup_for_android
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:LogErrorIfEnabled(String)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:FindGoogleServicesFile(ConfigFileType, String, FindGoogleServicesFileMode, LogMessage, LogMessage)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:ReadProjectFields()
Firebase.Editor.SettingsWindow:OnFocus()
UnityEditor.DockArea:OnEnable()
```

Did anyone had this error before(because I couldn't find anyone else with this problem) and how did you fix it?

Comment: I had a similar problem when first importing Firebase to my project. I remember finding a guy that said that restoring his Windows solved the problem for him. Unfortunately this was the only workaround that worked for me too. And I've tried a ton of things for days before appealing to it. Hope you have more luck than me! Is you .xml beeing generate at all? You can try to generate it yourself.

Comment: Have you tried following a different tutorial ? Their documentation is sometimes misunderstood. But should work out of the box as described (done in a project couple of months ago on 5.4).  Try following the steps of a visual tutorial; maybe this one will help? https://youtu.be/uj6rs3HFg5o

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge luckily reinstalling the firebase SDK did the job for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Download a configuration file](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en)

> Get a config file for your Android app
>   To download a config file for an Android app:
>
> Sign in to Firebase and open your project. Click the Settings icon and
>   select Project settings. In the Your apps card, select the package
>   name of the app you need a config file for from the list. Click
>   google-services.json.

[Add the SDK to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)

> Add the GoogleService-Info.plist file to the project.
>
> Navigate to the Assets folder in the Project window. Drag the
>   GoogleService-Info.plist downloaded from the Firebase console into the
>   folder. NOTE: GoogleService-Info.plist can be placed anywhere under
>   the Assets folder.

Comment: How does `Your apps` card look like?